# Crystal Report Cross Tab Conditional Formatting

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports (Version 13). I have to display date wise attendance register with some background color based on condition with some other column.
e.g

```
Emp#   Date           Hours   ApprovalStatus 
____   ____           ___      ___________
A01    01-May-19      8        A 
A01    02-May-19      8        A
A01    03-May-19      8        R
A02    01--May-19     8        R
A02-   02-May-19      8        A
..
..
etc
```

Currently I have designed the date wise crosstab report. But unable to display color (e.g red) to the relevant employee date entry whose status is other than 'A'.

**Note:** `ApprovalStatus` column is part of report datasource but this column is not included in crosstab.

[image]

Any one can help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the field/cell in the crosstab and select 'Format Field'.  Go to the 'Font' tab and right of the 'Color' field there is a formula icon.

Click on the formula icon and write your formula something like

```
 if approvalStatus <> 'A' then CrRed
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But solution did not work.
I have achieved like this through some work around. Added 'ApprovalStatus' column in cross tab Summarized fields and hide this field caption through 'Display Format String' and display Border color based on following code in formula editor
if currentfieldvalue='N' then
    crRed
else
    crWhite