# Surpress emtpy row in cross table (Crystal Reports)

Tags: crystal-reports, pivot-table

I am counting unique values in a crosstab, a blank value is also calculated as unique value.
For this purpose, an extra row is then correctly displayed in the crosstab. I would like to hide this row and can't find a way to do this.

[image: Cross tab example]

For me, only the rows with a real number are relevant.

**How do I suppress this complete row?**

Comment: I don't remember, but right click on that cell  and if there is hide option then add condition. If its not work, then the simply while fetching the data either from query or stored procedure, add condition to there which does not get this row at crystal report.

Comment: you can check this one- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56251232/crystal-report-cross-tab-conditional-formatting , 
   http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=9806 ,                                                                                     https://answers.sap.com/questions/11701504/cross-tab---conditional-suppression-for-a-column.html

Answer (score 0):

Crystal has no option to filter crosstab.
So you need to filter the report using a record selection formula.

If you can't filter the whole report because you need the blank cases in other areas of the report, place the crosstab in a filtered subreport.